# Routing Without Slash in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am preparing a mobile page for a web site. When guest open a link, php will redirect him/her to mobile page with same url if him/her device is mobile.

There are some problem. The urls like these `sitename.com/product-name-334` and `sitename.com/category_name_c`. They detect the page thanks of `_c` and product ids. But I dont know how can I provide it by angular?

I want to listen your suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You should try ui-Router's $stateProvider.

[StateProvider API Reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

1. First, you need to reference ui-Router in your index file.
2. Then, you can assign a state to a hyperlink by using data-ui-sref attribute.

   ```
          <li>
           <a data-ui-sref="product">

           </a>
       </li>

   </ul>`
   ```
3. Then you need to assign a url, a template and a controller to the state.

   ```
    angular.module('sspRouting', ['ui.router'])
   .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
         function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
             $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

             $stateProvider
                 .state('product',
                 {
                     url: "/productDetail/{productId}",
                     templateUrl: 'app/view/productTemplate.html',
                     controller: 'productController'        
                 })
           )}]);
   ```

Then inside the controller you can use $routeParams to get the id from the url and then build your html using the data of that specific product.

```
        .controller('productController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, productService) {
            var productId = $routeParams.productId;
            // your code here.
//example $scope.productDetail = productService.getProductDetail(productId);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your suggest, but there is another problem. I cant define a page to each product. There are about 700 products and I have to set those urls dinamically

Comment: I edited the post. I think this is more suitable to your needs